# Linux MAX11122 SPI driver - extra 300uS delay before pulling up CS

Tags: linux-device-driver, delay, spi, iio

I am trying to get data from a SPI ADC on a Linux v5.10 (imx8mp, no preempt RT patch).

First, I used shell commands and [spitools](https://github.com/cpb-/spi-tools) to interact with the chip and find out the configuration that suits my needs.

Example of command line:

```sh
printf '\x00\x00\x00\x00' | spi-pipe --device /dev/spidev1.0 --speed 1000000 --blocksize=2 --number=2 | hexdump -C
```

The next step was to create a proper Linux driver to be more efficient. Surprisingly, spying on the SPI bus gave me results I can't explain.

This is the kind of frame I'm having using command line / spi-pipe based on [spidev driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/drivers/spi/spidev.c).
Behavior is very consistent, the whole SPI exchange lasts for about 200uS, perfect for my needs.

[image]

This is the kind of frame I'm having using my custom driver, very inconsistent, most of the time I got one or multiple additional 300uS delay before releasing chip select.

[image]

[image]

In rare cases (I would say every 10th sample approx.), I got one with no delay:

[image]

This is the code I'm using in my custom driver to transfer SPI data:

```c
static int max11122_read_raw(struct iio_dev *indio_dev, struct iio_chan_spec const *chan, int *val, int *val2, long mask)
{
    int ret, i;
    struct spi_message m;
    struct max11122_state *st = iio_priv(indio_dev);

    mutex_lock(&st->data_lock);

    memset(st->tx_buf, 0, sizeof(st->tx_buf));
    memset(st->rx_buf, 0, sizeof(st->rx_buf));

    struct spi_transfer xfer[] = {
        {
            .tx_buf = st->tx_buf,
            .rx_buf = st->rx_buf,
            .len = 2,
            .cs_change = 1,
            .delay_usecs = 1,
            .cs_change_delay = {
                .value = 1,
                .unit = SPI_DELAY_UNIT_USECS
            },
            .word_delay = {
                .value = 1,
                .unit = SPI_DELAY_UNIT_USECS
            }
        },
        {
            .tx_buf = &st->tx_buf[2],
            .rx_buf = &st->rx_buf[2],
            .len = 2,
            .delay_usecs = 1,
            .word_delay = {
                .value = 1,
                .unit = SPI_DELAY_UNIT_USECS
            }
        }
    };

    toggle_cnvst_pin(st);

    ret = spi_sync_transfer(st->spi_dev, xfer, ARRAY_SIZE(xfer));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk("failed to get conversion data\n");
        mutex_unlock(&st->data_lock);
        return ret;
    }

    *val = cpu_to_be32(*((int *)st->rx_buf));
    *val2 = 1000000;

    mutex_unlock(&st->data_lock);

    return IIO_VAL_INT;
}
```

I tried a lot to tweek `delay_usecs`, `word_delay`, `cs_change_delay` but these seems to hold minimum values. So leaving these variables to 0 doesn't help apparently.

**Why do I have this behavior? What seems to be the reason(s) of these additional 300uS delays?**

Comment: What prevents you from (writing and) using in-kernel driver for the ADC? Note `spidev` exists **solely for debugging** purposes and must not be used otherwise.

Comment: Yes agree, current driver on linux master branch is obsolete. You have an error message saying it's using an old API. Plus it's quite minimalist so I reworked a driver on my side to suits my needs.

Comment: Cool! So, you can now upstream your changes that everybody else will benefit from your excellent job.